# How to get SHA of file after upload in PHP

Tags: php, sha

I have a site which copies a file from a URL to my sever.  I need a way of getting a SHA of the file after it has been copied.

I was using `@copy($url,$upload_path)` to copy the file but this returns a boolean I need something that returns the file.  Does anything like that exist?

I need to get the file afterwards for `sha1_file($file)`

Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just

```
if (@copy($url,$upload_path)) {
  $hash = sha1_file($upload_path);
}
```

`$upload_path` already contains the value you would need to pass to `sha1_file()`.

And, as a general rule, the `@` operator is evil. I will admit that this particular usage of it is arguably valid, but as a rule of thumb it should treated as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

`sha1_file` takes a filename.  The `$upload_path` you've supplied to copy is a filename.  You should be able to do:

```
sha1_file($upload_path)
```

to get your sha1.